# PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, october

[image: Беда]
Пытаюсь освоить плагиностроение на ОктоберЦмс
стоит опен сервер в настройках стоит
php5.6-x64
MySQL 5.5
Apache 2.4-x64

И конфигурационных файлах вроде все прописано правильно, но артисан постоянно ругается
В чем может быть причина и как её устранить?

Comment: Нужно раскомментировать в настройках PDO драйвер для mysql. **php.ini** `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`

Comment: причем сделать это надо для консольного РНР, который может иметь собственный рнр.ини. посмотреть расположение можно командой php -i

Comment: Если верить конфигу вам надо (sqlite, mysql, pgsql) драйвера все или какой то один не важно. На системах Linux при установке пакета с драйвером `>> apt-get install php5-mysql` его PDO компонент ставиться автомотически. Для Windows/Mac OS думаю так же.